# Single quotes as a part of an element of a Python list

Tags: python, string, escaping

I searched around the web but couldn't find an answer. How can someone add a single quote as part of an element of a list in python? For example,

```
foo = ['the']
```

simple enough. But what if I want something like this?

```
foo = [''the']
```

where the element is 'the, with the single quotation appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another quotation mark, just like below:

```
foo = ["'the"]
foo = ['"the']
foo = ['''"the''']
foo = ["""'the"""]
```

or use '\'

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of representing strings in Python (**to avoid this issue**):

```
some_string = '...'          # single quotes
some_string = "..."          # double quotes
```

Therefore, you can use the second one:

```
foo = ["'the"]
```

You can also escape the `'` character:

```
foo = ['\'the']
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use double-quotes when defining the string containing a single-quote character, or use single-quotes, and `\`-escape the inner single-quote:

```
"'the"
'\'the'
```

both work.

(Your question has got nothing to do with lists, only the string in your list...)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single quote `'\''` or surround the string in double quotes `"'"`.